# FragmentPagerAdapter and Pager NullPointerException. pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, pager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a problem. I have 4 pages. and I used the method that pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);... It is very well page swiping. However, When I called finish() at FragmentActivity, Error happened that Fragment BackStack NullPointerException.  How do I solve it?[image]

I have 4 fragments and one MainActivity that extends FragmentActivity. 
I use pager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
I want to make two buttons to exit the app or go back to previous Activity.

** Problem : When I called finish() method in MainActivity, Error happened upper picture.  I want to know a solution about this problem.

Comment: Log cat trace for null pointer exception please..

Comment: Why would you ever need to call finish? Let the user back out of the application. Post your relative code.

Comment: MainActivity 543 line is super.onDestroy() at onDestroy().

Comment: hmm.. finish() is for exiting App or going Back LoginActivity. Because LoginActivity finished previously, I should call finish() and startActivity() to go LoginActivity.